# Spring Boot Annotation Routing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, routes, annotations

I'm new on Spring framework and I have the next problem with mapping:

I have created a Controller called HomeController and a View called index.html.

I put the annotation `@Controller` above the name of class HomeController and I created a method `bienvenido` where I wrote the annotation `@RequestMapping("/bienvenido")` above.

The problem is, as much as I try to re-run the server and clean the cache, I can never access index.html throught localhost:port/bienvenido. But if I write localhost:port/ only, the index.html is shown then.

I'm looking up info and everybody uses that way or a similar way to do this, I don't understand what is happening.

This is my classes and my html file:

```
package controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/bienvenido")
    public String bienvenido() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bienvenido!</h1>

</body>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show your package structure? Is your `@Controller` being scanned properly by your main (BootApplication) class?

Comment: You have defined HomeController in controllers package.  Is your Main class also defined inside controllers..   If not you need to specify your base class in Main class.   Add Project structure if possible

Comment: Hi, this is my package structure:

com.learning.bienvenido
 -BienvenidoApplication.java
controllers
 -HomeController

and this is my Main Class

package com.learning.bienvenido;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BienvenidoApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(BienvenidoApplication.class, args);
 }
}

I don't do any configuration.

Comment: When you are running localhost:port/ is it showing your index page or another index page? If it is your index page, do you have a @RequestMapping("/"); defined somewhere or in a configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

After a while looking at my project I just realised that I was creating the packages out of the main package. I mean: the controller package was named only "controllers" instead "com.learning.bienvenido.controllers".

Thank you all!